# Fetching various parameters from a video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have used a basic HTML and jQuery plugin to create a video player, and in it I have a video which a user can view. Now I want to fetch various parameters such as number of pause, total  time taken by user to view the video, and time at the particular pause. I am unable to find any function which does this.

Comment: To those downvoting, it is a rather vague question, but I think they're probably looking for a starting point. I think it's an okay question.

Comment: @samanime: I don't think it's suitable for Stack Overflow. It's OK in the sense that it's fine to be a beginner at something, but there is a wide consensus that getting-started type questions do not fit here. There being no illustration of research or prior effort does not help either (though it could potentially be saved by the same).

Answer (score 0):

The element itself won't track any of that on it's own. Instead, you'll have to hook up your own events to track it.

You can track a number of events, such as `play`, `stop`, etc. (a full list can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)).

For example, to track "number of pauses", you could track the `stop` and `play` events.

```
let isPlaying = false;
let pausedCount = 0;

video.addEventListener('play', () => { isPlaying = true; });
video.addEventListener('stop', () => {
  isPlaying && pausedCount++;
  isPlaying = false;
});
```

To count as a "pause" (per my definition), it has to be playing and then stopped. So, I have a `boolean` to track if it is playing. When it is stopped, before changing the `boolean` to `false`, if it was playing, I add one to my count.

For any kind of metrics you want, you'll have to come up with your own logic to track it by listening to events.